# How to check if still connected to the network set by setProcessDefaultNetwork()

Tags: android, android-5.1.1-lollipop

I have the following code that sets the default network of my internet connection.

```
if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
    NetworkRequest.Builder builder = new NetworkRequest.Builder();
    builder.addCapability(NetworkCapabilities.NET_CAPABILITY_INTERNET);
    builder.addTransportType(NetworkCapabilities.TRANSPORT_CELLULAR);
    NetworkCallback networkCallback = new NetworkCallback() {
        @Override
        public void onAvailable(Network network) {
            boolean result = ConnectivityManager.setProcessDefaultNetwork(network);
            Log.d(TAG, "success? " + result);
        }
    };
    NetworkRequest networkRequest = builder.build();
    connMgr.requestNetwork(networkRequest, networkCallback);
    connMgr.registerNetworkCallback(networkRequest, networkCallback);
}
```

This works properly. However, later on, when I check using the following code:

```
ConnectivityManager connMgr = (ConnectivityManager)
    context.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);

NetworkInfo networkInfoMobile =
    connMgr.getNetworkInfo(ConnectivityManager.TYPE_MOBILE);

networkInfoMobile.isConnected();  // returns false!
```

This always returns `false`. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I did is I saved the `network` provided by `onAvailable()` callback. Then later, I checked the connectivity thru:

```
NetworkInfo networkInfo = connMgr.getNetworkInfo(networkFromOnAvailable);
networkInfo.isConnected();
```

Cheers!